# Invalid Length Argument

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, sapply

I want to convert all the coloumns of my dataframe to numeric format. So I use lapply

```
 data.frame(lapply(dat, numeric))
```

But this is showng me an **invalid length argument** error.
However, it is working when I tried with individual coloumns.

```
 lapply(dat$x.Type, numeric)
```

But then again I am left to wonder how to update the orginal dataframe with this.

I am guessing the solution to my problem is to run a loop applying lapply through all the coloumns .
The problem is I am having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `as.numeric` instead of `numeric`:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat, as.numeric))
```

Comment: It worked thankyou. Could you explain this in more detail though?
I mean what is basically the difference between [as.data.frame] & [data.frame] over here?

Comment: @AdhirajChattopadhyay There is no practical difference between `as.data.frame` and `data.frame` here. The latter constructs a new `data.frame`, in this case by using a data structure that is passed as an argument, while the former coerces a given data structure into a `data.frame`. Semantically I therefore prefer `as.data.structure` in this case.

Comment: what is the difference between as.numeric and numeric ?

Comment: `numeric` is used to declare a type of variable. Specifically, it creates a new vector of specified length of the type `double`. In contrast to this, `as.numeric` coerces existing data into numeric form, i.e., converts it into `double`.  If it helps, in other programming languages, a coercion/conversion like the one done by `as.numeric` is called "type casting".

Answer (score 0):

Another nice option if you already have an existing dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)
```